# SwiftyJSONにおけるエラーについて

Tags: swift3

```
import UIKit
import SwiftyJSON

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    private let OpenWeatherMapUrl = "https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=tokyo&appid=2adfa01395bd22a20c1f1c95158af3da"



    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    func openweathermap(){

        let url = NSURL(string: self.OpenWeatherMapUrl)!
        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url as URL, completionHandler: {data, response, error in
            let json = JSON(data: data!)
            print(json)

        })
        task.resume()

    }

}
```

このコードにおいて
`let json = JSON(data: data!)` の部分で

> Use of unresolved identifier 'JSON'

というエラーが出てしまい、解決できていません。

Swiftは ver 3.1 、 Xcode は ver 8.3.3 です。

Comment: `import SwiftyJSON`にはエラーは表示されていないでしょうか? _Use of unresolved identifier 'JSON'_のエラーはBuild/Runした時のエラーでしょうか? それともエディター画面に表示されているだけのエラーでしょうか?

Comment: import SwiftyJSONにはエラーは表示されていません。Use of unresolved identifier 'JSON'のエラーはエディター画面に常に表示されており、Build/Runすらできない状態です。

他のライブラリでも試したのですが、同様にimport ライブラリ名の場所ではエラーは表示されず、ライブラリ依存の記述をするとエラーが表示されます。

Comment: ご報告ありがとうございます。残念ながらかなり珍しい症状で、私が経験したり情報集めした中には`import`が通るのにBuild/Runすらできないと言うのは例がありません。Xcode8はビルドに失敗した時の情報(言わばゴミエラー情報)をいつまでも保持して再度表示することがあるため、それがもっと厄介な形で起こっている可能性はあると思います。Clean BuildやXcodeの再起動を何度か繰り返すことで類似のエラーが解消されたと言う報告もあります。空の新規プロジェクトを作成して、SwiftyJSONをゼロから組み込み直すと言うのはお試しになられたでしょうか、それで`JSON`を含むコードがコンパイルできるようなら、先に書いた「ゴミエラー情報」のせいと言うことになるのですが。また、他の場所にある単純エラーのせいでゴミエラー情報がクリアされないと言うこともあるようです。該当行をコメントアウトして完全にエラーが出ないようにしてから、再度コメントインしてビルドしてみる、などもお試しください。(それで解消できたこともある、と言う頼りない情報なので申し訳ないのですが。)

Comment: ご丁寧な返信ありがとうございます。cocoa pods経由でインストールしたのでcocoa podsのアンインストールから再度やり直してみたのですがやはり同様のエラーが出てしまいました。またエラー部分をコメントアウトしてビルドしてみたところ、importの部分ではエラーは起きず、let json = JSON(data: data!) を入れたところ同様のエラーが生じてしまいました。swift3.0.2、xcod8.2の方のMacで全く同じコードを使用したところエラーは起きない様子でした。

Comment: 「swift3.0.2、xcod8.2の方のMacで」エラーが起きないと言うことは、podで最新バージョンを指定していない可能性があるように思われます。最新リリース版を指定されておられるでしょうか?

Comment: コメントが遅れてしまい大変申し訳ございません。SwiftyJSONは最新バージョンを使用しています。clean buildもxcodeの再起動もやりましたし、新規プロジェクトももう一度やりましたがやはり間違った点は見受けられませんでした。単純なエラーも見当たりません。